# How to draw rounded corners around box with shadow

Tags: framed, text, box

I am trying to draw a text box with rounded corner and shadow like this:

[image]

I have no idea how to do this. The only I managed to do is this:

```
\noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        The content of this chapter has been published in the SRRW conference in 2017.  The work of this chapter is also extended to handle the ER problem. 
    }%
}
```

Which only draws a box but not with rounded corner and shadow.

Can someone please suggest me a solution?

Comment: Take a look at the `tcolorbox` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,drop shadow=black!50!white,colback=white]
The content of this chapter has been published in the SRRW conference in 2017.  The work of this chapter is also extended to handle the ER problem. 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

If you want to use the same style of box multiple times in your document, you can also define it in the preamble using `\newtcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}
{
  enhanced jigsaw,
  drop shadow=black!50!white,
  colback=white
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
The content of this chapter has been published in the SRRW conference in 2017.  The work of this chapter is also extended to handle the ER problem. 
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another idea considering the [`mdframed`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) package rev. 212 with the use of `TikZ`.
If you want to increase the rounded corner you increase the value `8pt`. And for the thickness of the border you increase the value of `middlelinewidth=2pt`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={draw=gray,fill=white},
          roundcorner=8pt,shadow=true]{mdboxshad}
\mdfsetup{%
middlelinewidth=2pt
}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdboxshad}
The content of this chapter has been published in the SRRW conference in 2017.  The work of this chapter is also extended to handle the ER problem. 
\end{mdboxshad}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another alternative without the use of `mdframed` can be with pure `TikZ` using the library `shadows` to make the `drop shadows` at the below-right:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=text, text width=\textwidth, draw=gray, rounded corners, line width=1.5pt, drop shadow={shadow xshift=.7ex, shadow yshift=-.7ex},fill=#1, inner sep=3mm] (big) {\\#2};
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
}
\begin{document}
\mybox{white}{The content of this chapter has been published in the SRRW conference in 2017. The work of this chapter is also extended to handle the ER problem.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I control the size of the xcolorbox? The one given above is of full \textwidth.

Comment: @StudentofStatistics Now I don't remember. Try asking a question referring to the question.